# How to retrieve Google App Engine entities by ancestor

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

I have the following 2 models in my Google App Engine datastore:

```
class Search(db.Model):
    what = db.StringProperty()

class SearchResult(db.Model):
    search = db.ReferenceProperty(Search)

    title = db.StringProperty()
    content = db.StringProperty()
```

And, I am trying to retrieve all SearchResult entities for a given Search entity in the following function:

```
def get_previous_search_results(what='', where=''):
    search_results = None

    search = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Search WHERE what = :1", what).fetch(1)
    if search:
        search_results = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM SearchResult WHERE ANCESTOR IS :1", search[0].key()).fetch(10)

    return search_results
```

However, it always returns an empty set.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?  I've read through the [Python Datastore API docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/) and this seem like the correct way to do this, but it's not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you creating the Search entities with a parent?  The ReferenceProperty doesn't create an ancestor relationship, and it seems likely you might want search.searchresult_set, which will be a Query for SearchResult objects that have a reference to the Search object 'search'.

Comment: If you want to make `SearchResult` a descendant of `Search` you have to create them with `a_result = SearchResult(parent=a_search, ...)`